# How to Design Binary Multiplier for 2 bits?

Tags: design

\$(X_1,X_0)*(Y_1,Y_0)=>(S_0,S_1,S_2,S_3)\$

What should I use here? Half Adders? Full Adders? MUX? What goes were?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think. You learned the on-paper multi-row method of decimal multiplication? Just transfer that to binary. All you need is addition (HA and FA) and multiplication (AND, but a suitably wired MUX will do fine). Your teacher was mild, in the assignement below I ask for a 4 x 4 multiplier :) The text it Dutch, but it might give you some hints. It also show  a block diagram of an 8 x 8 multiplier.

http://www.voti.nl/hvu/1ICSN1/2004-2005-1ICSN1-5-p.doc

Answer (score 2):

For such a minimalist requirement with only 16 4-bit words as it's complete 'solution space', a 16 x 4-bit read only memory or functional equivalent is fast and easy.

However—if this is for an assignment or as a general learning exercise that would not be a good solution. To know what the best solution is you'll need to tell us more about the actual question. What is it for? Why so tiny a range? How fast do you want it to be an/or does it matter? etc.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. It is an assignment we received after a class on HA/FA/MUX, there is no requirement of minimal, or fast solution. All they request is to design a binary multiplier for 2 bits.

Answer (score 2):

Just like the [long multiplication](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LongMultiplication.html) you learned in elementary school: multiply the multiplicant X by the least significant bit of the multiplier Y. Shift multiplicant one bit left and multiply by the multiplier's next bit. And so on, and add the partial products.

```
        X1  X0     <-- Y0 term   
    X1  X0         <-- Y1 term  
    -----------  
             A  
    B1  B0         Half-adder
C1  C0             Half-adder

C1  C0  B0   A     Result
```

The nice thing about binary multiplying is that it can be as simple as AND-ing: for the first line you AND X1 and X0 with Y0. If Y0 = 0 then that line is zero, otherwise it's X1,X0. So for the partial products we need 4 AND gates.

The rest is adding. A = X0 from the first line. Use a half-adder to add X1 from the first line to X0 from the second, giving B1,B0, and add X1 from the second line to B1, giving C1,C0.

Answer (score 1):

AND gate, followed by left bit-shift and ADD.

AND is the equivalent of a 1 bit multiply. You AND each bit of one argument with each bit of the other. You bit shift them accordingly, and add them all together at the end. It's just like multiplying on paper.

Answer (score 0):

One traditional method to be familiar with is to create a truth table in 2x2 grey code, seperate it into a separate it into a separate table for each bit of the answer giving you the form of a Karnaugh map, circle the groupings of 1's and express the collection for each answer bit as a sum-of-products.

Of course today, actual implementation is usually left to computerized tools which will take a variety of forms of expression as input and place or configure logic elements of the chosen (FPGA, ASIC, etc) technology as needed.

Answer (score 0):

For two-bits, the result is either going to be zero, the input, the input shifted left one place, or three times the input.  Although one could use an AND-SHIFT-ADD approach, that would be overkill when the input is only two bits.  One could use a four-input mux to select among the choices; the only choice that's even mildly hard is the last one, and that one only maps [X : Y]=(00,01,10,11) to (0000,0011,0110,1001).  Each of the four output bits from the (input times three) function can be expressed as a simple Boolean function of the two inputs.

Note that if you were constructing a slightly larger multiplier (e.g. 4x4), you might want to go with the "AND/SHIFT/ADD" approach suggested by wjin; if you were constructing a much larger multiplier (e.g. 32x32) you would almost certainly want to use a slightly different approach, probably combining Booth's Algorithm (which rewrites overlapping sequences of 3 bits into values from -2 to +2, thus avoiding the 3x case) with carry-save adders (given three numbers that need to be added, quickly compute a pair of numbers that have the same sum).  Note that adding two large numbers quickly requires a large amount of circuitry; doubling the size of the numbers will more than double the amount of circuitry required for the fastest possible addition, and the computation will still be slower than with the smaller numbers.  By contrast, both Booth's Algorithm and carry-save addition operate on small portions of a number without any need for a fast carry chain.

Answer (score 0):

> What should I use here? Half Adders? Full Adders? MUX? What goes were?

Say you want a practical circuit that is very fast and has a minimum number of chips.

1. Use a simple PLD device, say ATF16V8. It will do the job for about $1, in a single chip.
2. Use four 1:16 muxes, CD4067 or 74HC4067. Total cost is about $4.

   Feed all four input bits to the input select pins of the 4067. Configure the other 16 mux pins to the values in the truth table for one of the output columns. One mux per output column in the truth table.

Since this was a homework assignment, let's say I was the instructor, then I would expect, respectively:

1. Test WinCUPL file for the design.
2. A schematic that works.

Your instructor will probably have other ideas, though.

<sub>Approximate DigiKey prices as of the day this answer was written.</sub>